# How to format data to be entered in JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, jquery, active-directory

I am trying to format my data from active directory so that I can pass it through `JavaScriptSerialzer` and have it entered in JSON format.
Also it has to be in this format:
     `[{"id":"1","name":"Foo"},
     {"id":"2","name":"Bar"}]`

```
foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in search.FindAll())
{
    if (sResultSet.Properties["displayName"].Count > 0)
    {
            nameList.Add(string.Format("({0}-{1})",sResultSet.Properties["displayName"][0], sResultSet.Properties["mail"][0])); 
    }
}
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string output = serializer.Serialize(nameList);

return nameList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but some adjustments are necessary.

First, create a [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) type class to serialize it as you want and to transfer, for sample:

```
public class NameDTO
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

After it, create a list of this object and serialize

```
// create a list of DTO
var nameList = new List<NameDTO>();

// loop your data
foreach (SearchResult sResultSet in search.FindAll())
{
    // some custom condition
    if (sResultSet.Properties["displayName"].Count > 0)
    {
        // create a DTO object and fill it (i'm not sure about your code)
        var dto = new NameDTO() {
           Id = sResultSet.Properties["mail"][0],
           Name = sResultSet.Properties["displayName"][0]
        }

        // add on the list
        nameList.Add(dto); 
    }
}

// create the serializer object
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

// serialize the list of DTO and get the result json
string output = serializer.Serialize(nameList);
```

Comment: This seems to work but in this method I am trying to return an array and it seems I cannot convert the serialized nameList ToArray because of the DTO.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't have my return set to output. This worked and thank you very much.